# iOS - Have a good popToRootViewController and open a new UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I push a UIViewController twice in rootViewController(one by one) Now I want to back to rootviewcontroller and open a new UIViewController ,What shall I do?  I can use notification to achieve it ,but I really want to know a good way to achieve it .

Comment: use delegate or unwind?

Comment: I suggest that you push the new view controller and then manipulate the navigation controller's `viewControllers` property to remove the unwanted view controllers, so that "back" from the new VC takes you to the root

Comment: Thank for your answer , I have resolved it @Paulw11

Answer (score 0):

First I create a new UIViewController then I add it into viewControllers in navigationController , at least I use popToViewController to go to new UIViewController

Answer (score -1):

Think about it as a stack. First you in rootViewController, then you push two viewController in front of it.

All you need is

```
func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController?
```

So all you need is to pop twice to go back to rootViewController.